# Return every user’s default shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to put together a single command that will display each user's default shell. From researching I can mostly find commands to change the default shell, such as `chsh -s /bin/ksh` but not to do the task at hand.

Does anyone know how one might accomplish this on CentOS?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it

`getent passwd | cut -d: -f1,7`

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the `/etc/passwd` file, that contains the username and login shell listing along with other relevant info regarding all user accounts of the system.

The username is stored on `:` separated first, and login shell on seventh (last) field.

So you can use `awk` to print the fields with a bit of formatting in between for prettiness:

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1 " " FS " " $NF }' /etc/passwd
```

If you happen to use services like `ldap` that does not use local filesystem, you can use `getent passwd` to follow `nsswitch` to get the info, and then use `awk` over that:

```
getent passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $1 " " FS " " $NF }'
```

**Example:**

```
% awk -F':' '{ print $1 " " FS " " $NF }' /etc/passwd
root : /bin/bash
daemon : /usr/sbin/nologin
bin : /usr/sbin/nologin
sys : /usr/sbin/nologin
sync : /bin/sync
games : /usr/sbin/nologin
man : /usr/sbin/nologin
lp : /usr/sbin/nologin
mail : /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: `getent passwd` works for both local and remote user accounts, so you might as well use that in both situations...

Answer (score 2):

That information is stored in /etc/passwd:

```
cut -d: -f1,7 /etc/passwd
```